# How to convert data from GML to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr?

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, gml

How should I convert GML to geojson data using ogr2ogr.
I used :

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" bd.geojson bd.gml
```

But in this case I have only part of my data , not all.
I tried add -append , but it didn't work properly.

Comment: Please expand your question with an example feature from the gml and the geojson

Comment: I have many poligons , linestring and point in one file *.gml . When I converted to geojson I saw only poligons. I am thinking that there are possible the same "name" of records. And when I exported data to Postgis I used loop "for" and -append , because I had the same problem. But in this case I don't know how I should write script .

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure what the issue is based on your question, but you could try to use the `-nlt` flag (from documentation http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html). This will (explicitly) specify the output geometry type. Since you have mixed geometry you might try the command
`ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -nlt "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION" bd.geojson bd.gml`

Comment: I have to errors: ERROR 6: GeoJSON driver doesn't support creating more than one layer ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed      after changing ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -nlt "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION" bd.geojson bd.gml

Comment: What does "ogrinfo -al -so bd.gml" report?

Comment: How I can create simillar loop for gml->geojson?   _for %%I in (*.gml) do (

psql -c "drop table if exists -d %base% -h "%host%" -p %port% -U %user%
ogr2ogr  -append -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:dbname=%base% user=%user% password=%pass% host=%host% port=%port%" %%I -nlt GEOMETRY -lco PRECISION=NO)_

 It is working for POSTGIS for my complex data,

Comment: @Agnieszka It is working or it isn't working? You need a loop to convert all your gml to geojson or fix the loop you have? If the former, try `for %%I in (*.gml) DO (
 SET oldName=%%I
 SET newName=%oldName:.gml=.geojson%
 ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -nlt "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION" %newName% %%I
)`

Comment: I would rather try with `-nlt geometry` but we should really see the ogrinfo report. If source gml has several layers they must be converted one by one into several GeoJSON files.

Comment: Please, tell me what I have to put in blanks "newName,oldName" . In regards to last quastion , loop for my data only works when I export data to PostGis, I don't know how I should write the same for convert gml->geojson

Comment: Ogr info ....C:\konkurs>ogrinfo egib.gml
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `egib.gml'
      using driver `GML' successful.
1: EGB_DzialkaEwidencyjna (Polygon)
2: EGB_JednostkaEwidencyjna (Multi Polygon)
3: EGB_ObrebEwidencyjny (Multi Polygon)
4: EGB_Budynek (Multi Polygon)
5: EGB_ObiektTrwaleZwiazanyZBudynkiem
6: EGB_Klasouzytek (None)
7: EGB_KonturUzytkuGruntowego (Polygon)
8: KR_ObiektKarto (Point)
9: EGB_KonturKlasyfikacyjny (Polygon)
10: EGB_Malzenstwo (None)


C:\konkurs>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: That means that your GML contains many layers and dislike PostGIS GeoJSON can only have one layer as you have been informed `ERROR 6: GeoJSON driver doesn't support creating more than one layer`. Do `ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" bd_first_layer.geojson bd.gml EGB_DzialkaEwidencyjna` for converting the first layer.

Comment: I can not import this automatically ? I mean all layers.

Comment: Can I  import this automatically ? I mean all layers. Because when I do : ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" bd_first_layer.geojson bd.gml EGB_DzialkaEwidencyjna  I only import first class